# Angular 2 application hosted in child directory having relative path issues with systemjs after bundling

Tags: angular, typescript, gulp, systemjs

I am creating one single bundle file using sysmtemjs-builder buildStatic method.
My angular2 application is hosted as sub application on iis.

e.g

```
http://www.maindomain.com/subapplication/
```

when i create packed js file. All the views and style paths are pointing to main domain

```
http://www.maindomain.com/app/modules/testcomponent.view.html
```

It should be

```
http://www.maindomain.com/subapplication/app/modules/testcomponent.view.html
```

I have tried the following things,but none of them is wokring
Added the `<base href="subapplication" />`
Added module.id to every angular component.
Tried adding baseURL in my systemjs.config.js file

How can i append my child virtual directory path to views and styles only?

Here is my tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitUseStrict": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "rootDir": "./app"
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "files": [
    "app/main.ts",
    "typings/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Had you tried `<base href="/subapplication/" />` ?

Comment: this question is not about base path, could you please provide your systemjs config, tsconfig and sample options from component decorator?

Comment: @Poonam yes i tried the following <base href="subapplication" /> <base href="/subapplication/" /> <base href="/subapplication" /> nothing works

Comment: I am using the latest angular2 systemjs.config provided here
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html
adding ts config in question